# Java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.test.coretestapplication" could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I have a stage for testing in my build.xml file:

```
<target name="test">
    <untar compression="gzip" src="${sdkTarBall}" dest="${testDirectory}"/>
    <unzip src="eclipse-test-framework-3.4.2.zip" dest="${testDirectory}"/>
    <unzip src="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip" dest="${testDirectory}"/>

    <move todir="${eclipse-home}">
        <fileset dir="${testDirectory}/${archivePrefix}">
            <include name="*/**" />
        </fileset>
    </move>

    <property name="library-file" value="${eclipse-home}/plugins/org.eclipse.test_3.2.0/library.xml"/>

    <ant target="core-test" antfile="${library-file}" dir="${eclipse-home}">
        <property name="plugin-name" value="com.gansu.alltests" />
        <property name="classname" value="com.gansu.alltests.AllTests" />
    </ant>
...
```

We have upgraded eclipse to 4.8 version. Now we need to upgrade the eclipse-test-framework. I downloaded the it from here. [url](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.8-201806110500). But it looks like it leaks the `${library-file}` file. Did the method of running the tests changed? Or am I missing something?

Edit: I downloaded the `eclipse-Automated-Tests-4.8.zip` and copied the library.xml file from there. While running the `ant` command I get:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.test.coretestapplication" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.gansu.application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
```

How do I install `org.eclipse.test.coretestapplication`? Where I can find it? Is it inside `eclipse-test-framework-4.8.zip` or `eclipse-Automated-Tests-4.8.zip`? Could not find it there.

**EDIT2:** I actually see it under the eclipse installation:

```
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.test_3.4.100.v20180426-1922/org/eclipse/test/CoreTestApplication.class
```

But why it says that it can't find it?